# Jmeter - How to tell loop controller to loop for all the numbers from 0000 -> 9999 && and exit once status code 200 is being reached?

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario where I need to loop for all the numbers from 0000 to 9999, and once reached status code 200, to exit the loop.

My script looks like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I put the static number into Loop controller works fine

[image]

But: How to lead Loop controller based on the counter element && exit the loop once status code 200 is being reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this on one shot using [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter/) and the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

```
${__groovy(vars.put('counter'\, new java.text.DecimalFormat('0000').format(Double.parseDouble(vars.get('__jm__While Controller__idx') ?: 0))); vars.get('counter') != '0005' && ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode() != '200',)}
```

No other test elements/loops/whatever are required

Comment: thanks for the answer, I put the above code into While Controller, and disable counter, but my HTTP request as such, is not running at all.

Comment: Of course it won't because you have the `002` sampler which is successful and has response code `200` so the condition is not met. If there are other Samplers before the While Controller you will need to add a [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter) as a child of the `004` request, configure it to save response code into some variable and replace  `ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode()` with `vars.get('your_variable_name')`

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
You can exist a loop control when a condition is satisfied with an [If controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action).

[image]

1. Set following in the IF controller

```
${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
```

[image: If controller checking the status of the last sampler]
2. Set `Break Current Loop` in the Flow Control Action

[image: Flow control action breaking the current loop]

**Note**: You shall add a delay after checking the status of the last sampler. This can be achieved with a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer)

**Option 2**
You could achieve this with a JSR223 Post-processor too.

1. Add a [JSR223 Postprocessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to your HTTP Request

[image]

2. Add the following into the script window

```
if (vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok").toBoolean()){
    ctx.setTestLogicalAction(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.BREAK_CURRENT_LOOP )
}
```

[image: JSR223 Post Processor]

API Documentation : [Test Logical Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.html), [JMeter Context](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#setTestLogicalAction-org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction-)

**Option 3**
Add [Results Status Action Handler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Result_Status_Action_Handler) Postprocessor to the HTTP Request and set `Break Current Loop`

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, however, is it possible within a single command place into Loop controller, or ultimately using some other controller such as while controller?

Comment: ex: ${__groovy((vars.get('__jm__While Controller__idx') as int) < 20 && (vars.get('Status_Code')  as int) < 200 ,)}

Comment: @vlatko606 You should give it a try and see if it's working. BTW **Option 3** is the easiest solution for you. Just add a [Result Status Action Handler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Result_Status_Action_Handler) to your **004 Verify/One Time Password** request. I would suggest using a timer to introduce a delay between the failed requests. This can be achieved by adding a constant time below the request **004 Verify/One Time Password**